# How to convert 32-bit VBA code into 64-bit VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro code that worked in 32-bit (used to work) but since I just upgrade my machine, I'm using a 64-bit Excel  and this code is not working anymore. I need to make this work in 64-bit. Please help me to fix this please:

```
AdoConn 
     .ConnectionString = “provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=“ &  strFileSource & “;Persist Security Info=False” 
     .Open
```

It shows the problem in .Open

Thank you so much.

Comment: The 32 bit code will work, but you need to have the 32 bit drivers installed too

Comment: *this code is not working anymore* is far too vague to be useful. In what way is it *not working*?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/jet-odbc-driver-available-32-bit-version

Comment: Do you really ***need to use*** 64-bit Office?  If not, install the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find an incompatibility with the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 (32 bit) driver in 64 bit OS.

You can use the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 (32 bit) driver on a 64 bit OS, but you must force your application to build in in 32 bit mode.

If you don't want to, or cannot do that, there is a 64 bit version of the driver available (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) which works on 32 & 64 bit OS.

Try changing:

```
.ConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" &  strFileSource & ";Persist Security Info=False"
```

to

```
.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &  strFileSource & ";Persist Security Info=False"
```

If the driver is not registered on your machine, it can be downloaded from the Microsoft website: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Also, not it's not just the 4.0 changing to 12.0, 'Jet' changes to 'ACE' as well.